# json post httppost parameter missing for android

Tags: android, json

In my below code I am posting a json string to a server. Though I have writtenn postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data", jsonStr)); it gives error that parameter json_data is not passed.

I am not sure why it is giving me error.

```
OrderjsonArray.put(order1);
LocationjsonArray.put(location1);
LocationjsonArray.put(location2);
order1.put("locations", LocationjsonArray);

JSONObject ordersObj = new JSONObject();

ordersObj.put("orders", OrderjsonArray);

String jsonStr = ordersObj.toString();

String contentType = "application/json";
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data", jsonStr));
HttpGet httpGet = null;
try {
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
    entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", contentType);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

}
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below Code

```
try {
                                HttpPost httppost1 = null;
                                HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                if (userchk.equalsIgnoreCase("client")) {
                                    httppost1 = new HttpPost(
                                            ApplicationData.serviceURL
                                            + "/clientLogin");
                                } else if (userchk.equalsIgnoreCase("driver")) {
                                    httppost1 = new HttpPost(
                                            ApplicationData.serviceURL
                                            + "/driverLogin");
                                }

                                Log.e("9", "9");

                                // Add your data
                                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                                        2);
                                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                        "vEmail", email.getText().toString()));
                                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                        "vPassword", password.getText()
                                        .toString()));

                                httppost1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                        nameValuePairs1));
                                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                                HttpResponse response1 = httpclient1
                                        .execute(httppost1);
                                BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(response1
                                                .getEntity().getContent()));
                                StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("");
                                String line1 = "";
                                while ((line1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb1.append(line1);
                                }
                                in1.close();
                                Log.e(userchk + " login original data",
                                        sb1.toString());
                                return sb1.toString();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                return "";
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the json text as the value for a name value pair. But the rest of your code implies that you have to send it as multipart formdata. Apparently the server does not look at name value pairs also.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. I am not getting your point here please.

Comment: Just search on this site examples where a post is done with content type `application/json` and you will see.